# Black screen after switching from NVIDIA to AMD videocard

Tags: graphic-drivers

I recently switched to a new videocard, but now I'm getting a black screen whenever I boot to elementary OS. I do see a splash screen before it goes black.

How can this be resolved?

Any help with removing the old drivers, installing the new ones or tools for debugging this issue would be greatly appreciated.

I booted again and I saw an error this time:

```
*ERROR* No UMS support in radeon module
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can boot on your system by select "RecoveryMode" on "Advanced option for elementaryos" inside GRUB 2.

[image: Ubuntu advanced boot]
<sub>(source: [instructables.com](https://cdn.instructables.com/F52/JUNA/HET0RS1T/F52JUNAHET0RS1T.LARGE.jpg))</sub>

Next, use failsafe X to use CLI only mode

[image: Failsafe X]

Then, install fglrx package.

```
apt-get update
apt-get install fglrx
reboot
```

fglrx install ATI catalyst. Normally it remove nvidia drivers by using DKMS. Fingers crossed !

Finally, you can test your system !

Good luck ;)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Sadly, I cannot see failsafe X in the recovery menu.

Comment: Maybe you can continue by selecting resume mode, try this =)

Comment: I can go to terminal via ```ALT+F1``` once the screen is black. I'll try your commands that way. I've updated my question with an error message I saw when booting.

Comment: Other than that, ```apt-get install fglrx``` correctly removed nvidia drivers and guess what: I booted to desktop. Thanks! (EDIT: now I seem to have some troubles with my mouse and keyboard not responding, but that's another issue).